# Unable to build test ActiveJDBC project in IntelliJ

Tags: activejdbc

Bottom line up-front:  Here's the error I'm getting within IntelliJ:

`Failed to execute goal org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.2:instrument (default-cli) on project hsdart: Failed to add output directory to classpath: org.javalite.instrumentation.InstrumentationException: javassist.NotFoundException: getClassName(..) is not found in net.hintsight.dart.models.ExtractDescriptor -> [Help 1]`

The build works from the CLI, just not from within IntelliJ.  Here's the step I added to test builds:

`org.javalite:activejdbc-instrumentation:1.4.2:instrument`

Other important bits:

- IntelliJ version:  15.0.2
- Maven version:  3.3.9
- Java version:  1.8.0_101
- ActiveJDBC version: 1.4.12

Full output from IntelliJ:  http://pastebin.com/wfpE5umK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your ActiveJDBC version maybe 1.4.12, but the version of the instrumentation plugin is 1.4.2. Please, upgrade the plugin  to  the same as the library and try again.

Comment: Sure enough, the log output says the plugin is 1.4.2.  However, I had 1.4.12 already specified in my POM.  Is there a reason that the version being used is different than the version specified in the POM?

Comment: I'm accepting the answer because switching both to "1.4.2" worked.  However, I had both set to "1.4.12" and it did not work.  I think there's an issue there, but this allowed me to move past it.  Thanks!